# Strong equivalence of metrics that metrize the weak-* topology on the unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. By the sequential Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the unit ball in $X^*$ is compact in the weak-* topology and this topology is metrizable.

Let $\{x_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ and $\{\xi_j\}_{j \in \mathbb N}$ be two countable systems in $X$ and let

\begin{eqnarray}
d(y_1,y_2) &:=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} \frac{|\langle y_1 - y_2, x_i \rangle|}{1 + |\langle y_1 - y_2, x_i \rangle|}, \tag{1} \label{eq:d1} \\
d'(y_1,y_2) &:=& \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} \frac{|\langle y_1 - y_2, \xi_j \rangle|}{1 + |\langle y_1 - y_2, \xi_j \rangle|}. \tag{2} \label{eq:d2}
\end{eqnarray}

Both metrics metrize the weak-* topology on the unit ball in $X^*$ (e.g., Theorem V.5.1 in the first volume of Dunford-Schwartz), hence they are topologically equivalent.

**Question:**
Are there any sufficient conditions, under which these metrics are *strongly* equivalent, i.e.
$$
cd(y_1,y_2) \leq d'(y_1,y_2) \leq Cd(y_1,y_2) \quad \forall y_1,y_2 \in X^*
$$
holds for some $c,C >0$?

Comment: what do you mean by equivalent?

Comment: What is your definition of equivalent metrics? The usual definition is two metrics are equivalent if they induce the same topology. This is obviously true here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I understand this in the sense that $c  d(y_1,y_2) \leq d'(y_1,y_2) \leq C d(y_1,y_2)$ for some $c,C >0$. (I edited the post accordingly)